# two controls beneath each other

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I want to create a label control and also, I want to put the border around the label control. I want to show a radio button inside that border so something like this

```
  <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:label ID="lblJCN" Text="JCN"  runat="server" ackColor="#808080" Width="100px"
                                                Height="30px" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#333333"></asp:label>

                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbJCN" runat="server" Text="or" />

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
```

I want Or radio button to be inside the label control lblJCN border. Is it possible to do that?

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, to achieve having the label with a border and a radio button inside, try this

```
<fieldset>
<legend><asp:label ID="lblJCN" Text="JCN"  runat="server" ackColor="#808080" width="100px"></asp:label></legend>
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdbJCN" runat="server" Text="or" />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: The radio button is showing outside the border of the label, in other words the radio button is not inside the grey area/border of the label.

Comment: I put the background color in legend and got the desired result. thanks for sharing the fieldset and legend tag with me. I didn't know about it. Thanks again for all yur help